# Как можно подсчитать запросы hibernate делает к БД?

Tags: hibernate

```
package spring.app.service.impl;

import com.vladmihalcea.sql.SQLStatementCountValidator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import spring.app.dao.abstraction.GenreDao;
import spring.app.model.Genre;
import spring.app.service.abstraction.GenreService;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@Transactional
public class GenreServiceImpl implements GenreService {

    private final GenreDao genreDao;

    @Autowired
    public GenreServiceImpl(GenreDao genreDao) {
        this.genreDao = genreDao;
    }

    @Override
    public void addGenre(Genre genre) {
        genreDao.save(genre);
    }

    @Override
    public Genre getByName(String name) {
        return genreDao.getByName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Genre> getAllGenre() {
        List<Genre> genres = null;
        SQLStatementCountValidator.reset();
        System.out.println("начинаем отсчёт");
        genres = genreDao.getAll();
        SQLStatementCountValidator.assertSelectCount(1);
        return genres;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateGenre(Genre genre) {
        genreDao.update(genre);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteGenreById(Long id) {
        genreDao.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Genre getById(Long id) {
        return genreDao.getById(id);
```

Мне нужно получить число. Сколько hibernate делает запросов при выполнении метода. Я буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык, иначе его закроют.

Comment: На Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Включите логирование в настройках и посмотрите

Answer (score 0):

можно включить статистику,

```
StatisticsService statisticsService = new StatisticsService();
statisticsService.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
statisticsService.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
```

дальше приложение работает и мы захотели получить количество запросов:

```
System.out.println(statisticsService.getQueryExecutionCount());
```

[ссылка](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/jmx/StatisticsService.html#getQueryExecutionCount())

Comment: Hibernate StatisticsService устарела с 4.0 и удалена в hibernate 5.2.1.

Comment: в 5.4.10.Final все еще есть  [ссылка](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#statistics-query) 5.4 - Latest stable